# Integral of convolution difference approaches zero

Tags: integration, limits, convolution

> Let $u(x,t)=f(x)\ast\left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\dfrac{(at+x)^2}{4t}}\right)$, and suppose that $f\in L^1$. Show that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|u(x,t)-f(x)|dx=0$$

How can I prove this statement? $|u(x,t)-f(x)|$ is some ugly convolution, then we integrate over $\mathbb{R}$ and take the limit $t\rightarrow 0^+$.

Comment: I don't think you can not show what you claim. What you need to show is $$ \lim_{t \to 0+} |u(x,t) - f(x)| = 0$$.

Comment: @Tom Could you explain why I can't show what I claim? Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite sorry, I misread the problem. Your statement is fine! You want to show $L^1$ convergence.. what I stated doesn't really make sense pointwise because you only know that $f \in L^1$.

Comment: @Kunal: You can find in a lot of books the proof of a very similar statement, which says that $$f\star \left( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\right) \to f\quad$$ in $L^1$ sense as $t\downarrow 0$. Try to adapt it to the present case. I think that this should work